# Accessing the name of the function when multiple functions are returned

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a basic function, that can be called around my project using different names - `tiger`, `lion`, `dog`.

I'd like to access the name of the triggered name within the function its self.

For example:

I can run `demo.tiger('Hello', {1:1})` and like to access the `tiger` name from within the trigger function.

Thanks

```
const demo = ({ }) => {

    function trigger (message, context) {

        console.log(message, context);

    }

    return {
        tiger: trigger,
        lion: trigger,
        dog: trigger
    }

}
```

Comment: There's no way to know. If the function cares, it should be a parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Barmar suggested, you have to pass it through as an argument if you really want it.

```js
const demo = () => {
  function trigger(message, context, caller) {
    console.log(message, context, caller);
  }

  return {
    tiger: (message, context) => trigger(message, context, 'tiger'),
    lion: (message, context) => trigger(message, context, 'lion'),
    dog: (message, context) => trigger(message, context, 'dog'),
  };
};

const x = demo();

x.tiger('a', { 1: 1 });
x.lion('a', { 1: 1 });
x.dog('a', { 1: 1 });
```